# How to use groovy Abstract Syntax Tree ast in multi-module gradle project

Tags: gradle, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I've not found any way to use groovy `Abstract Syntax Tree` in a gradle multi-module project. Whenever I try to copy an example such as from [here](https://gist.github.com/ilopmar/6037796), the annotations do not work. It would be great to find a full working sample I could leverage.

**No Progress**
I've been trying to research how to do this but have not hit anything. [Here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9517) there is an open issue about exactly this in gradle. Having a separate module just does not seem to work for me I do not know why.

I've also tried [this](http://nimavat.me/blog/apply-groovy-ast-in-same-project-with-custom-gradle-ast-sourceset) which doesn't work either. Was for an older version of gradle though.

Comment: You want to write a local AST Transform?

Comment: Any AST at this point, but sure local.

Comment: So if you start simple and create an annotation with an associated transformation class, where is it failing for you?

Comment: the ASTs work if only defined in another (sub-) project of your gralde config

Comment: @injecteer I assumed as much, but still doesn't work when I do that.

Comment: This is ridiculously hard to get to work...

Comment: show your project structure, where the AST is residing and how you use it

Comment: Ast is in another module `ast`. And other modules depend on it through the normal `implementation(project('ast'))`

Comment: I have the same setup. If I annotate my classes/methods with `@MyASTAnnotation`, it works like a charm. I have some `println`-calls in my ASTTransformation, so I can see if the nodes are processed in compile phase